# Как правильно: "связанном" или "связанным"?

Tags: склонение, причастия, причастный-оборот

*Ремонт на объекте, не связанном с проживанием, расположенном по адресу...*

или

*Ремонт на объекте, не связанным с проживанием, расположенным по адресу...*

Answer (score 2):

Пишется так:

***ремонт на объекте (какОм?), не связаннОм с проживанием, (какОм?) расположеннОм по адресу...***

Окончание прилагательных и причастий помогает определить вопрос.